# Format/flag cells based on spellcheck in Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2013. I have a column with several words. I want to divive them into three categories:

1. Words that match a dictionary word, like plane, customer, help, etc
2. Words that contain a dictionary word, like planecs, customer11, helpmgmt, etc
3. Words that do not match any of the above

I guess if I just flag 1 and 2, the rest are 3. By flagging them I mean, if a cell is in category one, turn the background green for example. If category 2, turn the background red, something like that, as long as I can sort them. If they cannot be sorted by background color, let's create another column next to it, and if a word is in category 1, the cell next to it should say Category 1, so I can sort that way.

Note; I want to use the standard dictionary (American English) built into Excel. I don't have a separate dictionary file or row of 'dictionary' words.

Thanks!

Comment: Thoughts, anyone? Thanks

Comment: Any Excel ninjas have any thoughts? Thanks!